# How to display messages in SBT?

Tags: sbt

Is there an equivalent to the ant echo statement in SBT? For example:

```
<echo message="Hello, world"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use println() in SBT Task
http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13.5/docs/Detailed-Topics/Tasks.html

```
println("Hello, world")
```

Answer (score 5):

From a task, you may use `streams`, for example: `streams.value.log.info("an info message")`

From settings, you can use `sLog.value` which is a `Logger` and analogous to `streams.value.log`